# Magento models and security

Tags: database, model

I made a custom module which is actually a bit extended contact form module. I'm saving form data into database.

Is it save just to call **$model->save()** with values from POST?
This is how I save data:

> $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('partnercontact')
>
> $model->addData($data); $model->save()

May I suppose that Magento sanitize values before saving it into database or my module is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: what is mean by "May I suppose that Magento sanitize values before saving it into database?
data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->getRequest()` should return an instance of `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http` that extends `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`.
From what I know zend sanitizes the request values.
And the actual sql insert and update uses an instance of `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` that extends `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`. This one also should sanitize the queries.

But you can never be too careful.

Answer (score 3):

You may not suppose that Magento will sanitize the input, you need to take care of that yourself.

If you target the post data directly you will be open to malicious input.

In your controller's php you want to call something like below:

```
$userInput = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user input element name here');
```

where $this is an extension of `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`.

And if you're outputting user input back to the page, you will probably want to sanitize that using the `escapeHtml()` method.